# ScaffoldMessenger is not working in below await key

Tags: flutter, dart

**My code details**
I tried to initialise the scaffold message. It works normally, but the problem is below the "await" key; it's not working. If you find it, explain why this is not working and how I can fix it.

```
                          onTap: () async {
                              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                try {
                                  final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
                                  final scaffoldMessenger =
                                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
                                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                    content:
                                        Text("responseMessage!.message.toString()"),
                                  )); //This ScaffoldMessenger is working
                                  UserDetails userDetailsSend = UserDetails(
                                      name: name.text,
                                      email: email.text,
                                      phoneNumber: int.parse(phone.text));
        
                                  responseMessage =
                                      await UserData().register(userDetailsSend);
        
                                  if (responseMessage!.status == 201) {
                                    navigator.push(
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => OTPVerificationScreen(),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  } else {
                                    scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                      content:
                                          Text(responseMessage!.message.toString()),
                                    )); // scaffold is not working
                                  }
                                } catch (e) {
                                  debugPrint(e.toString());
                                }
                              }
                            }
```

**The first ScaffoldMessenger is working, but the second scaffoldMessenger  is not working. How do I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, i have changes some code, if it will not work please let me know -

```
onTap: () async {
  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
    try {
      final navigator = Navigator.of(context);

      // Show the first SnackBar
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("responseMessage!.message.toString()"),
        ),
      );

      UserDetails userDetailsSend = UserDetails(
        name: name.text,
        email: email.text,
        phoneNumber: int.parse(phone.text),
      );

      responseMessage = await UserData().register(userDetailsSend);

      // Delay a bit before showing the second SnackBar
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
        final scaffoldMessenger = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
        if (responseMessage!.status == 201) {
          navigator.push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => OTPVerificationScreen(),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(responseMessage!.message.toString()),
            ),
          );
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm already trying this Future.delayed, it's not working, now I try this code, still not working, and I have the same error.

Comment: share your project  through github, u can add me - https://github.com/champ0011?tab=repositories